# How To Do Conditional Back Navigation for Global Action - Android Nav Component

Tags: android, global, back, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

In my app, I have 3 screens - Sent List, Received List & Item Details Fragments. I am using the Android Navigation Component Architecture. The Details Fragment can be navigated to by a Global Action directly from the Activity (in case of a notification).

**It's just that if the Item in the Details Screen is a Received Item, I want it to go back to the Received Items List. But it is going back to the Sent Items.**

The back navigation works just fine when I go from the respective List Fragments (Sent & Received) to the Item Details Screen. This just doesn't work on the Global Action. Here is my current code in my `MainActivity` when I receive the notification:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
navController.navigate(
    NavGraphDirections.actionShowItemDetails(),
    NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(if (type == SENT) R.id.sentListFragment else R.id.receivedListFragment, false).build()
)
```

This does not work. What do I do?